# Mark searched text and jump from result to result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a little search box. This box marks text and when searching for a new text, it will clear the current results and mark the new results.

You can see it here

```js
var defaultText = null;

function setDefaultText(){
    defaultText = $("#loremIpsum").html();
}

function search() {
    var keyword = $("#searchBar").val(),
        textSource = defaultText;

    keyword = keyword.replace(/(\s+)/, "(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");

    var pattern = new RegExp("(" + keyword + ")", "gi");

    textSource = textSource.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
    textSource = textSource.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/, "$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

    $("#loremIpsum").html(textSource);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="setDefaultText()">
        
        <div id="searchContainer">
            <input id="searchBar" type="text" placeholder="Search..." onchange="search()">

            <p id="loremIpsum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet.
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
                eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
                est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
                ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
                dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                amet.</p>
        </div>
        </body>
```

How can I get the results and show them in a box? I want to jump from result to result. Like a searchbox as we know it.

[image: Chrome searchbox]

When typing keywords, the box should collect the results, count them and when clicking the searchbox buttons "up" or "down" it should jump from the current result to the previous or next result.

Marking the text should be fine, as you can see in the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use regex to put all results in a `<mark>` tag you can use that tag to achieve your goal.

Get a list of all the `<mark>` tags by using `$("mark")`.

Count the size of that list, those are the amount of results.

For the arrows to jump between results use the [prev](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function to get the previous or next `<mark>` tag, or simply use a counter and select it from the `$("mark")` list. You can scroll to the selected result using [scrollTop](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/prop_element_scrolltop.asp).

To hightlight the current result you might want to use some CSS class to highlight it in a different color. Use [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [removeClass](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) to highlight the currently selected result.

Edit: A crudely made version would look like this:

```js
var defaultText = null;
var results = null;
var currentResultIndex;

function setDefaultText() {
  defaultText = $("#loremIpsum").html();
}

function search() {
  var keyword = $("#searchBar").val(),
    textSource = defaultText;

  currentResultIndex = -1;

  keyword = keyword.replace(/(\s+)/, "(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");

  var pattern = new RegExp("(" + keyword + ")", "gi");

  textSource = textSource.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
  textSource = textSource.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/mark>)/, "$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

  $("#loremIpsum").html(textSource);

  results = $("mark");

  if (results.length > 0) {
    currentResultIndex = 0;
    setResultText();
    focusResult();
  }
}

function goToNextResult() {
  currentResultIndex++;

  // When going next on last element, jump back to first
  if (currentResultIndex >= results.length) {
    currentResultIndex = 0;
  }

  setResultText();
  focusResult();
}

function goToPreviousResult() {
  currentResultIndex--;

  // When going previous on first element jump to last
  if (currentResultIndex < 0) {
    currentResultIndex = results.length - 1;
  }

  setResultText();
  focusResult();
}

function setResultText() {
  $("#resultCounter").html((currentResultIndex + 1) + " of " + results.length);
}

function clearSearch() {
  $("#searchBar").val("");
  search();
  $("#resultCounter").html("&nbsp;");
}

function focusResult() {
  // Get element of current result
  var targetElement = results[currentResultIndex];

  // Remove hasFocus css class from the previous result
  $("mark").removeClass("hasFocus");

  // Add hasFocus css class to current result
  $(targetElement).addClass("hasFocus");
  $('html, body').scrollTop($(targetElement).offset().top - 50); // account for the 50px  margin-top from body
}
```

```css
searchBar {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  margin-top: -40px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

p {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

.hasFocus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="setDefaultText()">
  <searchBar>
    <input id="searchBar" type="text" placeholder="Search..." onchange="search()">
    <p id="resultCounter">&nbsp;</p>
    <button id="searchResultNext" onclick="goToNextResult()">Next</button>
    <button id="searchResultPrevious" onclick="goToPreviousResult()">Previous</button>
    <button id="searchClear" onclick="clearSearch()">X</button>
  </searchBar>
  <p id="loremIpsum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
    et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
    tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
    sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
    no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
    dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
    voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
    labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
    sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
    est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
    clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
    accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
    erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
    sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
    no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
    dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyubergren, no sea
    takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
    et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

</body>
```

Comment: This is my current code,would you mind helping me finishing the rest? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeywKV

The website crashes when testing it :X

Comment: ps: the website crashes because you insert an unnecessary window.open function in it. Opening the target element which is not an url, which results in a 404.

Comment: yes this is really awesome. just wondering why my code is not scrolling the page :X

Comment: use scrollTop instead of focus, apparantly focus only works on input fields